# Multiplying big numbers (arrays) without Java API

Tags: java, arrays

Hello people of programming,

numbers are stored backwards in as-small-as-possible integer arrays:

```
int[] numberA = {7, 3, 6, 2, 1}; //representing number 12,637
int[] numberB = {7, 3, 3};       //representing number 337
```

Now I want to code a function that returns the product of those two numbers:

```
static int[ ] times(int[ ]a, int[ ] b) {
    //numberA x numberB = product
    return product;
}
```

Because 12,637 x 337 = 4,258,669 the returned array should look like this:

```
product = {9, 6, 6, 8, 5, 2, 4};
```

All this should work without using the helping force of the Java API (eg. `java.util.ArrayList`).
I have already created similar functions in the same script that can be used:

- adding two number(arrays)             (`int[] add(int[] int[])`)
- multiplying with single-digit integer (`int[] timesInt(int[], int)`)
- copy an array                         (`int[] copy(int[])`)
- create number(array) from int         (`int[] fromInt(int)`)

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried (code-wise, yourself) so far? This reads off like a homework assignment

Comment: You could try And extract an `int` value, ie. `12637` from the Array using a loop. Is this what you want ?

Comment: @Rogue Actually I tried to modify the "add"-function to fit multiplication but I failed to generate arrays with dynamic length. I also tried to mimic the steps of multiplying numbers by pen/paper (like in elementary school) by slipping in zeros to sum up the final product

Comment: @TheRedRabbit - assuming no trailing zeroes in the strings, length of the product will be A.length + B.length - 1. Your approach of inserting zeroes' to the front of the strings during multiply operations and using your add function should work. You should probably get this working first before looking at optimizations like Karatsuba.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the Karatsuba or the Cook Algorithm? Perhaps you can implement them?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication

Comment: While the link might lead to a solution, it's not as good as writing the answer, seeing as links can get broken.

Comment: These are well known algorithms, so if the links are broken you can find them easy somewhere else.

Comment: In this case, you are correct. However, this isn't usually the case.

Comment: @kleineLotti Vielen Dank! I didn´t heard of such algorithms and will read through the articles

Comment: gern, have fun, they are really basic and well known!

Answer (score 0):

I have this program which will create result as you have posted in your question, I haven't used any of java API like arraylist as you have specified, code is:

```
public class Test
{

static int[ ] times(int[ ]a, int[ ] b) {

    String astr="",bstr="";

  for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
      astr=astr+a[i];//Converts the int array's to string to reverse them without any other than String methods.
  }

  for(int i=b.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
      bstr=bstr+b[i]; //Converts the int array's to string to reverse them without any other than String methods.
  }

  int var1=Integer.parseInt(astr); // Converting the reversed string back to int for computing result

  int var2=Integer.parseInt(bstr); // Converting the reversed string back to int for computing result

  long result=var1*var2; //Computing result


   String newstr=String.valueOf(result); // Converting the final result back to String


   int temp[]=new int[newstr.length()];// Creating the array to hold final result in it

    int counter=0;

    for (int i =newstr.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {

        String nwresult="";
        nwresult=nwresult+newstr.charAt(i);  //reversing the final answer string

         temp[counter++]= Integer.parseInt(nwresult); //Returning the final answer string by converting it to integer

    }

     return temp;

}


 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     int[] numberA = {7, 3, 6, 2, 1}; 
     int[] numberB = {7, 3, 3};  

     int array[]=times(numberA,numberB);

     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.print(array[i]);
     }

     System.out.println("");

  }

}
```

Comment: I think the goal here is to multiply the strings without conversion to integer.